# Import a CSV into a JS variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, variables

Trying to find the best method of importing and storing a CSV into a variable in Node.

Currently the program was setup to compare against the data being entered in the js files manually however that's become to slow to update and a waste of time. But the idea is moving it to check a CSV file that they can update daily for the time being since this is done already.

Data example below is what the program works with already:

```
var compareData = {
              "20": {"item": "490583450-00", "type": "metal"},
              "26": {"item": "934793292-00", "type": "plastic"}
              };
```

As for the CSV part, the CSV is your standard MS Excel CSV:

> ID,item,type
>
> 20,490583450-00,metal
>
> 26,934793292-00,plastic

I can't get the variable to stick in some way to be used later. But I can see that its being parsed correctly with the following.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var iFile = fs.createReadStream('data.csv');
parser = csv.parse({columns: true, 'objname': "ID"},function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
})
iFile.pipe(parser);
```

Comment: Why not just store the data into another global property? What do you mean you can't get it to stick? E.G. `var parsedData = iFile.pip(parser);`

Comment: @Dandy That outputs a bunch of data like: Transform { options: columns: [ ...., auto_parse: false, relax: false, ....etc etc etc

Comment: In your function you're logging not returning anything, change `console.log(data)` to `return data`. The parse function needs to return something into the parser.

Comment: @Dandy Tried that already but it just outputs the same result as my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

[JsonFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) allows you to save and read JavaScript Objects as a .json file, and provides an OS-agnostic API, so your code can store data locally on any machine.

I wrote a [simple Node program](https://github.com/dirtysanchez69/eecs-yorku/) that uses this library.